# How to use Java 8 Optional for mentioned situation?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Lets say I have a pojo `Medicine`,

```
class Medicine{
    private String xmedicine;
    private String ymedicine;
    private String zmedicine;

    //getter and setter here....
}
```

Below API used to collect medicine if medicine is not null.

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> gettMedicine(Medicine medicine) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> detailsList = null;

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        if(null != medicine.getXmedicine()){
            list.add(medicine.getXmedicine());                              
        }
        if(null != medicine.getYmedicine()){
            list.add(medicine.getYmedicine());                              
        }
        if(null != medicine.getZmedicine()){
            list.add(medicine.getZmedicine());                              
        }
        if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list)) {
            detailsList = //calling other API to get details from list;
        }
        return detailsList;
}
```

Is it preferred to use java 8 `Optional` here to eliminate `NullPointerException` as I have multiple null checks making my code boilerplate.

If yes then can you please suggest how can I use `Optional` here?

Comment: Your code won't have less boilerplate: you'd still have to check if the optionals are empty. You would have less boilerplate and less exceptions if you didn't return null from methods returning a collection. Never do that. return an empty collection instead.

Comment: Since your `list` can never be `null`, you shouldn’t use that 3rd party library method whose only purpose is the questionable `null` handling. Instead of `if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list))`, just use `if(!list.isEmpty())`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not use `Optional` for fields in a class or to replace it with null checks like in your ifs. In this case you can do the following:

```
Stream.of(medicine.getXmedicine(), medicine.getYmedicine(), medicine.getZmedicine())
       .filter(Objects::nonNull)
       .collect(Collectors.toList())
```